# How to specify the targetframework for nuget dependencies?

Tags: .net, .net-core, nuget

I have created a private nuget package with targetframework Netstandard 2.0
This package has a dependency on EntityFrameworkCore and EntityFramework.DbContextScope.

This works perfectly fine if I use this in a .Net Core project, but not in a .net Framework 4.6.1 project.

The package EntityFramework.DbContextScope is causing the issues. I had a look at the source code in nuget and saw this in the project.json

```
"frameworks": {
"netstandard1.3": {
  "imports": [

  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational": "1.0.0"
  },
  "buildOptions": {
    "define": [
      "EFCore"
    ]

  }
},
"net46": {
  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework": "6.1.3"
  },
  "buildOptions": {
    "define": [
      "EF6"
    ]
  },
  "frameworkAssemblies": {
    "System.Data": "4.0.0.0"
  }
},
```

If I install my nuget package in a .net framework 4.6.1 project it will automatically install EntityFramework 6 as well, but I created my Nuget package with EntityFrameworkCore.

Can I make a change in my Nuget package so it will always install EntityFramework.DbContextScope with targetframework netstandard instead of net46?

EDIT: The only way I could make this work until now is manually editing the hintpath in the csproj file of the .net framework 4.6.1 project. This works, but is far from ideal.

```
 <Reference Include="EntityFramework.DbContextScope, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.DbContextScope.1.0.0\lib\netstandard1.3\EntityFramework.DbContextScope.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52074984/10576762) may be helpful as it shows how to specify dependencies based on the target framework.

In your case, it may look something like:

```
<dependencies>
   <group targetFramework="v4.6.1">
      <dependency id="NETStandard.Library" version="1.6.0" />
      <dependency id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" version="1.0.0" />
   </group>
</dependencies>
```

If you want it to always install these versions of the dependencies regardless of the target framework, you can also leave the target framework unspecified:

```
<dependencies>
   <group>
      <dependency id="NETStandard.Library" version="1.6.0" />
      <dependency id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" version="1.0.0" />
   </group>
</dependencies>
```