# Target specific dependencies NuGet

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, nuget, .net-standard

I have the following dependencies in my .nuspec file:

```
<dependencies>
        <group>
          <dependency id="Dep1" version="2.4.11" />
          <dependency id="Dep2" version="1.0.4" />
          <dependency id="Dep3" version="1.0.4" />
          <dependency id="Dep4" version="1.0.0" />
          <dependency id="Dep5" version="1.0.4" />
          <dependency id="Dep6" version="1.0.4" />
        </group>
    </dependencies>
```

I've created a local nuget server and I'm installing this NuGet package in a Xamarin Forms solution.

The thing is that in the Android part of the solution it will install, but in the .netstandard part it will complain that Dep 4, 5, 6 are only for MonoAndroid (which is correct). I don't need the dep 4,5 and 6 in my .netstandard solution.

> NU1202: Dep4 1.0.0 is not compatible with netstandard2.0
>   (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). Package Dep4 1.0.0 supports:
>   monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0) NU1202: Package Dep5 1.0.4 is
>   not compatible with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0).
>   Package Dep5 1.0.4 supports: monoandroid44 (MonoAndroid,Version=v4.4)

How can I separate dependencies per targetFramework? I've tried multiple variations of groups within the dependencies category, but nothing will solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thoroughly reading

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#dependencies-element

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/target-frameworks

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/nuget-manual

it can be summed up to:

> Version 2.0+
>
> As an alternative to a single flat list, dependencies can be specified
>   according to the framework profile of the target project using 
>   elements within .
>
> Each group has an attribute named targetFramework and contains zero or
>   more  elements. Those dependencies are installed together
>   when the target framework is compatible with the project's framework
>   profile.
>
> The  element without a targetFramework attribute is used as the
>   default or fallback list of dependencies. See Target frameworks for
>   the exact framework identifiers.

Therefore in my case it would be:

```
    <dependencies>
       <group targetFramework="MonoAndroid10">
          <dependency id="Dep1" version="2.4.11" />
          <dependency id="Dep2" version="1.0.4" />
          <dependency id="Dep3" version="1.0.4" />
          <dependency id="Dep4" version="1.0.0" />
          <dependency id="Dep5" version="1.0.4" />
          <dependency id="Dep6" version="1.0.4" />
       </group>
       <group>
          <dependency id="Dep1" version="2.4.11" />
          <dependency id="Dep2" version="1.0.4" />
          <dependency id="Dep3" version="1.0.4" />
        </group>
    </dependencies>
```

This way when I'm installing the package on the .netstandard project it will check the targetFramework and see that it's not MonoAndroid and it will fallback to the element without a targetFramework and use only Dep1, Dep2 and Dep3. 
For the MonoAndroid10 project it will do the same and use all of them.